# spring jdbc failed to connect remote mysql while localhost is ok

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbc, intellij-idea

This is my jdbc property (use `com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource`):

```
jdbc.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://myserveraddress:3306/mydatabasename?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
jdbc.username=myusername
jdbc.password=mypassword
```

When `myserveraddress` is `localhost` or `my local ip address`, everything is ok :)

However, when `myserveraddress` is `my server ip address` (outside the LAN), exceptions come :(

```
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: An attempt by a client to checkout a Connection has timed out.
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: An attempt by a client to checkout a Connection has timed out.
Caused by: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.TimeoutException: A client timed out while waiting to acquire a resource from com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@6c4f5d64 -- timeout at awaitAvailable()
```

Actually, I have tested the server address by cmd, HeidiSQL, IntelliJ IDEA, and everything is ok…

[cmd ping and cmd mysql connection is ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tca7q.png)

[HeidiSQL connection and IntelliJ IDEA mysql connection test is ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIL99.png)

Confused, appreciate for your help

Answer (score 0):

First check that your port (3306) is open on this webpage http://portchecker.co/ (from outside, router may block your port for incoming connections), if not:

-Make port forwarding on your router

OR

-Put your server to DMZ on your router

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I dont think it's the server port problem since I can connect to my server db by cmd (mysql -u -h -p), and IDEA also tests the mysql connection successfully.